# Google captcha with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

i'm try to using Google Captcha with Angular JS, My problem is that the div "recaptcha" does not appear always. I think this is because the google captcha script loads before my other scripts have finished loading.

When the div appears, everything works as it should.

Does anyone know how to make everything work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that reCaptcha library `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit" async defer></script>` is included in head tag. The onload callback is necessary to notify angular-recaptcha library that reCaptcha api is ready for usage.

Comment: I don't use angular-recaptcha

Comment: However, try to include the reCaptcha library in the head tag